# calling function from within function not working

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am very new to app scripts. What I would like to do is to create a pop up message in google sheet, when proposal probability is goin above 75% - directing the user to go to a google form to fill.

When I call the "popup" function from outside - it is working. 
When I embed it into the If formula and I try to call it from there, it is not working, but the other instruction called in same place is executing properly.

I do not understand what is wrong.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Pipeline track');
  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getColumn() == 11) {
    var value = range.getValue();
    if (value >= 0.75) {
      range.setValue(1);
      showAnchor('Capacity planning', 'https://docs.google.com/');
    } else {
      range.setValue(0);
    }
  } else {
    range.setValue(10);
  };

}


function popup() {
  showAnchor('Capacity planning', 'https://docs.google.com/');
}

function showAnchor(name, url) {
  var html = '<p>Your proposal reached the stage where we need to reflect it in our operational pipeline - with basic project details </p> <p>Please fill in the below Google Form!</p> <html><body><a href="' + url + '" target="blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">' + name + '</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, "Capacity planning");
}
```

Comment: You need installable triggers. Simple triggers don't have permission to show Ui dialogs.

Comment: @TheMaster "Simple triggers don't have permission to show Ui dialogs" Have you got a reference for that? I've just tested one and it works OK (unless of course, I have a residual effect from the API from some prior, unrelated work???). Correction: I tested an alert which is not the same as a dialog.

Comment: @Tedinoz Modal html dialogs?

Comment: @TheMaster Why did I ever question you ;-) `showModalDialog` returns "Execution failed: You do not have permission to call showModalDialog". Ditto for "Prompt Dialog" - "Execution failed: You do not have permission to call prompt"

Comment: @Tedinoz TBF I didn't realize alerts are excluded from the usual restrictions of simple triggers. Seems like a nice way to spam someone ;)

Comment: Thank you both for answering to this so quickly! Is it possible to use url within alert? I do not need anything fancy, just a pop up saying here is the link, go fill it out. If not, off I go to google installable triggers...

Comment: It's not hard to implement an installable trigger. Just go from the GAS editor to `Edit->Current Project's triggers` and then `Create a new trigger`

Comment: @Orsi An alert can include the URL, but it is not “clickable” (I did try). Much better AND easier to go the installable trigger route.

Comment: @Tedinoz - thank you for trying it out, based on all of your advices I solved it with installable triggers, and works perfect!